# python transitions lib - Wait for multiple events before transition from single state possible?

Tags: python, transition, fsm

Cross-post from github issue https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions/issues/247.

I'm using python's transitions FSM library and I need to wait for 3 things to happen before I transition to the next state.

```
State = WAIT_FOR_3_THINGS
Events = thing_1_done, thing_2_done, thing_3_done
```

The thing_*_events can come in any order, so I'd prefer to avoid having a:

`thing_1_and_2_done`, `thing_1_and_3_done`, `thing_2_and_3_done` states

I can track events, 1, 2, & 3 and advance with a

```
conditions=[thing_1_and_2_done, thing_1_and_3_done, thing_2_and_3_done]
```

but I'm not sure where best to aggregate these event occurences.

Is there a more skookum (ok, pythonic) way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a pragmatic point of view your [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45515401/1617563) is the way to go with transitions, imho. For problems like this, concurrent state machines might be worth a look.

For this particular case this surely is over the top though but I'd like to use the opportunity to show how transitions might handle concurrency.
More precisely, we can use its ability to deal with multiple models to implement concurrency.
In the example below I extended `Machine` with a) a method to trigger an event on all models and b) with a method that initialises worker models and stores the actual models in an internal variable (this is not a proper stack though).
With `ignore_invalid_triggers`, every worker waits for the corresponding event and removes itself from the `ParallelMachine` model list when its done. When the model list is empty, `ParallelMachine` restores the actual model state again.

```
from transitions import Machine


class WorkerModel:

    def __init__(self, machine):
        self.machine = machine

    # I show myself out when I am done
    def on_enter_Done(self):
        self.machine.remove_model(self)


class ParallelMachine(Machine):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._pushed_models = []
        super(ParallelMachine, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # save actual models and initialise worker tasks
    def add_worker(self, tasks):
        self._pushed_models = self.models
        self.models = []
        for t in tasks:
            self.add_model(WorkerModel(self), initial=t)

    # trigger an event on ALL models (either workers or actual models)
    def trigger(self, trigger, *args, **kwargs):
        for m in self.models:
            getattr(m, trigger)(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.models:
            self.models = self._pushed_models
            self._pushed_models = []
            for m in self.models:
                getattr(m, trigger)(*args, **kwargs)


class Model:

    def __init__(self):
        # the state list contains model states as well as worker states
        states = ['Idle', 'Processing', 'Done', 'need_1', 'need_2', 'need_3']
        # potentially got_1/2/3 all can trigger a transition to 'Done'
        # but the model will only be triggered when the worker list
        # has been emptied before
        transitions = [['process', 'Idle', 'Processing'],
                       ['got_1', ['Processing', 'need_1'], 'Done'],
                       ['got_2', ['Processing', 'need_2'], 'Done'],
                       ['got_3', ['Processing', 'need_3'], 'Done']]
        # assigning machine to a model attribute prevents the need
        # to pass it around
        self.machine = ParallelMachine(model=self, states=states,
                                       transitions=transitions, initial='Idle',
                                       ignore_invalid_triggers=True)

    def on_enter_Processing(self):
        self.machine.add_worker(['need_1', 'need_2', 'need_3'])

    def on_enter_Done(self):
        print("I am done")


model = Model()
machine = model.machine
assert model.state == 'Idle'
# we use ParallelMachine.trigger instead of model.<event_name>
machine.trigger('process')
assert model.state == 'Processing'
machine.trigger('got_3')
machine.trigger('got_1')
# duplicated events do not matter
machine.trigger('got_3')
assert model.state == 'Processing'
machine.trigger('got_2')
# worker stack was empty and 
assert model.state == 'Done'
```

This way the global state may be "Processing(need_1/need_2/done)" or "Processing(done/need_2/done)" without the need of explicitly modelling all variants.

Concurrency is on `transitions` To-Do list but requires some changes. For instance, callbacks are expected to be available in all models (removing `on_enter_Done` from `Model` will raise an Exception for instance).

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using a set to define a list of events I wanted to accumulate before transitioning to the next state.

eg:

```
deps_required = {'got_thing_1', 'got_thing_2', 'got_thing_3'}
```

Adding an instance variable to the FSM instance to track this that was cleared on entering 'idle' state:

```
self.run_deps_set = set()
```

then, aggregating and checking the event sub-types in an condition clause:

```
def if_run_deps_ready(self, event):
    self.run_deps_set.add(event.args[0])
    return self.run_deps_set.issuperset(deps_required)
```

Doesn't feel super squeaky clean but I don't hate it (too much).

Answer (score 0):

No idea if this is a great, or even good, solution but you could consider threading or multi-processing each thing as a function and including a var at the end of each which flips true when it's complete.

Then a simple if a-complete, b-complete, c-complete bools-are-true check should get you where you want to go.

Comment: No real need for threads here as events are processed sequentially, so you could do the same thing in the main FSM processing thread. That's kinda where I was going with the FSM instance accumulator var. It just feels dirty managing a sub-state within a heavyweight FSM instance.